# How can i verify if a Contextmenu exists upon right click?

Tags: testcomplete

I need to verify if a right click menu/Context menu appears on clicking a specific element in my WPF application.
At present, my script fails when i use the entire reference of the Context menu after the right-click. Is Find Child a good option?
I am using TC9 and jscript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the **FindChild** method to make sure that an object exists and visible. For example:

```
function Test1()
{
  var orders = Sys.Process("Orders");
  var listView = orders.WPFObject("HwndSource: MainForm").WPFObject("MainForm").WPFObject("gridMain").WPFObject("OrdersView");
  listView.ClickR(106, 82);

  var menu = orders.FindChild(["NativeClrObject.Name", "VisibleOnScreen"], ["ViewContextMenu", true], 10);
  if (menu.Exists)
    Log.Message("The menu is displayed");
  else
    Log.Error("The menu is not displayed");
}
```

A tricky thing here can be getting the properties of the context menu object since it can be not listed in the Object Browser while the menu is not displayed. To overcome this, use the [Object Spy](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/57702/) tool with the **Point to the object and fix** feature.